# How to use returned String value from a method in SQL query

Tags: java

I've one method of `getSites()`, which returns all site_names from csv file. Now I want to use that returned string variable in SQL query. This is the `getSites()` method:

```
public class ReadCSVFile {

    public static String getSites() {
        // .csv comma separated values
        String csvFile = "C:\\data.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String sites = "";

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sites = sites + line + ",";
            }
            sites = sites.substring(0, sites.length() - 1);
            // System.out.println(sites);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return sites;
    }
}
```

This is the value I want to use in this SQL query:

```
String query = select NodeID, Site_Name from csproperties where Site_Name IN ("+sites+") ORDER BY Site_Name
```

So, when I pass the value of string in `("+sites+")`, the query variable will fire and based on the site_names I will get the API output.

Now I have created a class file of GFNSService under com.gds.service package, where I have created method getRigStatistics of an API and under this method I want a code to get sites value under this  ("+sites+") of sql query as given below -

```
@GET
```

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("/getRigStatistics")
public List getRigStatistics(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString) {
            logger.info("API method getRigStatistics invoked.");

```
        if (!isAppDynamicsUserAuthenticatedRigStatistics(authString)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
```

List rigList = new ArrayList<>();

```
        String query = "String query = select NodeID, Site_Name from csproperties where Site_Name IN ("+sites+") ORDER BY Site_Name";.....and so on  code to map properties.....
```

So, basically I want a code that where I should create a method into getRigStatistics method to get that sites values into ("+sites+").

Comment: sql isn't Java. are you struggling with the java part, or with sql?

Comment: I'm struggling in java part though, I want to create a method which put value in that block ("+sites+")

Comment: what do you get now?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any value, but I want to know the code that how to write a method to get the value from sites and return value of that method should come into ("+sites"+).

Comment: The correct query is this - String query = select NodeID, Site_Name from csproperties where Site_Name IN ("+sites+") ORDER BY Site_Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your string returned by `getSites()` looks like something like below:

```
String sites = "site1,site2,site3,site4";
```

which you can not use in a SQL query because the syntax for same should look like:

```
SELECT .... IN ('site1','site2','site3','site4') ...;
```

To get such a string from your method, one possible way might be to change:

```
 return sites;
```

to

```
return Stream.of(sites.split(",")).collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Or, if you don't want to use streams, change

```
String sites = "";           to    String sites = "'";
sites = sites + line + ",";  to    sites = sites + line + "','";
sites = sites.substring(0, sites.length() - 1); to  sites = sites.substring(0, sites.length() - 2);
and keep return sites;
```

Comment: Sir, I would like to show my original code to you... I think you got my question..can you suggest how can I show you my code....

Comment: @ManuSPanicker Just edit your question and post your code so everyone else can see it. The more people see it the more help you get. If there is some sensitive data in your code just remove or mask it with dots .........

Comment: Hi Eritrean, I'm getting Central Azeri','East Azeri' like this in the output, missing one single quot at the beginning  ......but I want in this format 'Central Azeri','East Azeri'......and so on

Comment: Got it sir, It was my mistake I didn't updated the variable from String sites = "";           to    String sites = "'";

Comment: Got the solution, I just passed the get method return variable into String sites.....String sites = ReadCSVFile.getSites();